# RA-02 SX1278 LoRa strange behavior in data output

Tags: types, arduino, output, lora

Yesterday I started working with my LoRa modules on Arduino. I used the example sketches to understand how they work. Now I want to check the received values to do certain things, like switching LEDs on and off.

My problem is that the received values are correct with the raw example sketch of the LoRa library but start to be incorrect as soon as I try to store them in variables.

Here's the code I've written to get the received values.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("LoRa Receiver");

  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // try to parse packet
  int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();

  if (packetSize) {
    // received a packet
    Serial.print("Received packet '");
    byte buffer[packetSize];
    int index = 0;
    // read packet

    while (LoRa.available()) {
      Serial.println((char)LoRa.read());
      buffer[index] = LoRa.read();
      index++;
    }
    char result = char(buffer);
    Serial.println(result);
  }
}
```

Note: NOT everything of this my code. I partly took the example sketch to help me out.

The console output of this looks like this :

```
Received packet '3' with RSSI -73
⸮
Received packet '4' with RSSI -85
⸮
Received packet '5' with RSSI -84
⸮
...
Received packet '8' with RSSI -83
⸮
Received packet '9' with RSSI -83
⸮
Received packet '1' with RSSI -82
⸮
```

The sender does nothing special but counting up to 16 and then start from the beginning. This is just a very basic task but as I am not very familiar with this technic I don't understand how I can get this to work. Meaning that I get values instead of ´?´. The second problem is that the numbers that are greater than 10 get shrunk to 1.

I hope that you can give me some constructive help or at least hints how I could make this work.

Answer (score 0):

```
char result = char(buffer);
Serial.println(result);
```

You're printing a `char`, not a decimal value. So yeah, expect to have single-byte weird chars.

```
uint8_t result = char(buffer);
Serial.println(result);
```

Will give you a head start.